# Почему в Visual Basic пишут иногда Me!а, а иногда Ме.a?

Tags: vba, visual-basic, ms-access

Я новичок в MsAccess просматривая код заметил, что некоторые строки кода используют `Ме.btn_X.SetFocus` а некоторые `Ме!formA`? В чем разница?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Восклицательный знак используется для разделения имени коллекции и имени элемента коллекции.

Точка используется для разделения имени объекта и имени его свойства или метода.

Поскольку коллекция является объектом, то для тех коллекций, в которых имя элемента является ключом, допустимо ссылаться на элемент коллекции с использованием в качестве разделителя как точки, так и восклицательного знака.

То есть записи **CollectionName!MemberName** и **CollectionName.ItemsProperty("MemberName")** эквивалентны.

Хотя лучше стараться использовать строгий синтаксис.

Из исходного сообщения - следующие варианты эквивалентны (при условии, что btn_X - это имя экземпляра класса, а не имя класса):

```
Ме.btn_X.SetFocus
Ме!btn_X.SetFocus
Ме.Controls("btn_X").SetFocus
```

Впрочем, если btn_X - это имя класса, то обращение к его методу не имеет смысла (при условии, что SetFocus есть имя метода, а не странно названное свойство, конечно).

Comment: Что-то сомнительно...

Comment: Ммм... а по какой причине, позвольте полюбопытствовать?

Comment: Понял, почему сомнительно. Потому что форма (а Me - это ссылка на форму) не является коллекцией, вероятно. Но тут уже особенности реализации от Microsoft - ссылка на объект одновременно есть и ссылка на свойство этого объекта по умолчанию, а для формы Default Value - это её коллекция Controls.

Comment: Нет, сомнительно из-за того, что твой ответ вообще не говорит о том, что `!` и `.` - это принципиально разные понятия. Скорее он говорит обратное.

Comment: Добавил в свой ответ про формы.

Comment: Если верить Майкрософт, то они пишут дубово: _There are three operators that you can use in an identifier: bang operator (!), dot operator (.), square brackets operator ([ ]). You use these operators by surrounding each part of the identifier with square brackets, and then joining them by using either a bang or a dot operator. The bang operator tells Access that what follows is an object that belongs to the collection that precedes the bang operator._ Как хочешь, так и понимай, никаких расшифровок.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52513/discussion-between-qwertiy-and-akina).

Answer (score 2):

В VB есть такое понятие, как свойство по умолчанию. Его [нельзя](//www.cpearson.com/excel/DefaultMember.aspx) добавить в редакторе VBA, но можно импортировать класс, в котором оно прописано. Это свойство примечательно тем, что оно неявно вызывается при использовании объекта не как объекта (т. е. в присваиваниях без `Set`, либо в обращении через круглые скобки). Восклицательный знак служит синтаксическим сахаром для передачи строкового аргумента этому свойству.

---

Импортируем следующий класс:

```
VERSION 1.0 CLASS
BEGIN
  MultiUse = -1  'True
END
Attribute VB_Name = "Magic"
Attribute VB_GlobalNameSpace = False
Attribute VB_Creatable = False
Attribute VB_PredeclaredId = False
Attribute VB_Exposed = False
Public Property Get Value() As String
    Value = "`Value` is accessed via dot"
End Property

Public Property Get Smth(Optional Key As String = "none") As String
Attribute Smth.VB_UserMemId = 0
    Smth = "`Smth` is accessed with `" & Key & "` argument"
End Property

Public Function Go()
    Debug.Print Me.Value
    Debug.Print Me.Smth("Any")
    Debug.Print Me!Any
    Debug.Print Me("Any")
    Debug.Print Me!Value
    Debug.Print Me("Value")
    Debug.Print Me.Smth
    Debug.Print Me!Smth
    Debug.Print Me("Smth")
    Debug.Print Me
End Function
```

и используем его из макроса:

```
Public Sub Test()
    Dim Obj As Magic
    Set Obj = New Magic
    Obj.Go
    Dim Var As String
    Var = Obj ' No `Set` here
    Debug.Print Var
    Debug.Print Obj![With a space]
    Debug.Print Obj("With a space")
End Sub
```

И вот что получится:

```
`Value` is accessed via dot
`Smth` is accessed with `Any` argument
`Smth` is accessed with `Any` argument
`Smth` is accessed with `Any` argument
`Smth` is accessed with `Value` argument
`Smth` is accessed with `Value` argument
`Smth` is accessed with `none` argument
`Smth` is accessed with `Smth` argument
`Smth` is accessed with `Smth` argument
`Smth` is accessed with `none` argument
`Smth` is accessed with `none` argument
`Smth` is accessed with `With a space` argument
`Smth` is accessed with `With a space` argument
```

Или, если разбирать по строкам:

```vb
Debug.Print Me.Value         ' `Value` is accessed via dot
Debug.Print Me.Smth("Any")   ' `Smth` is accessed with `Any` argument
Debug.Print Me!Any           ' `Smth` is accessed with `Any` argument
Debug.Print Me("Any")        ' `Smth` is accessed with `Any` argument
Debug.Print Me!Value         ' `Smth` is accessed with `Value` argument
Debug.Print Me("Value")      ' `Smth` is accessed with `Value` argument
Debug.Print Me.Smth          ' `Smth` is accessed with `none` argument
Debug.Print Me!Smth          ' `Smth` is accessed with `Smth` argument
Debug.Print Me("Smth")       ' `Smth` is accessed with `Smth` argument
Debug.Print Me               ' `Smth` is accessed with `none` argument
```

`none` используется из-за необязательности аргумента `Optional Key As String = "none"` при обращении к свойству `Smth`.

В последнем примере мы используем Me не как объект, поэтому также происходит обращение к `Smth` без передачи параметра. Та же ситуация происходит в

```vb
Var = Obj ' No `Set` here    ' `Smth` is accessed with `none` argument
Debug.Print Var
```

т. е. мы можем обращаться к дефаултному свойству не только изнутри объекта, но и просто имеея соответствующий объект в переменной. Тут можно было бы проделать всё то, что делалось в `Go` только с `Obj` вместо `Me`, но я не стал копипастить.

Как я уже сказал, `!` служит синтаксическим сахаром для передачи строкового аргумента дефаултному свойству. При этом накладывается ограничение, что передаваемая строка должна являться валидным идентификатором. Однако, отдельного упоминания заслуживают квадратные скобки, позволяющие использовать в качестве идентификатора всё что угодно:

```
Debug.Print Obj![With a space]    `Smth` is accessed with `With a space` argument
Debug.Print Obj("With a space")   `Smth` is accessed with `With a space` argument
```

---

Большинство встроенных коллекций присутствует дефаултное свойство, позволяющее обращаться к элементам коллекции по ключу.

В случае с формой есть ещё одна особенность - все созданные в дизайнере контролы объявляются `WithEvents`-свойствами, что позволяет обращаться к ним через точку (ну либо просто по имени). Но в то же время её дефаултным свойством является `Controls`, которое по ключу, а именно имени контрола, предоставляет сам контрол. Так что в случае с контролами выходит так, что к ним можно обратиться двумя способами (точнее, только к тем из них, которые созданы в дизайнере формы; к динамическим можно только через `!`). Замечу, что обращение через точку более эффективно.

---

PS: Аналогично будет с присваиванием, если написать соответствующий код.